# A tool-tip close to code blocks to copy code quickly

Tags: feature-request

When the posted code is long enough and with long horizontal lines, viewing the code becomes a problem in the browser due to horizontal and vertical scrolling. This is a bigger problem on a mobile device. The selection of the code block becomes tedious and more often than not requires multiple efforts to select properly.

So, a small icon somewhere around the code-block to put the code block into the clipboard can be really helpful and also a good time-saver.

Comment: One wonders why you are doing so much copying of code out of Stack Overflow. That is a very bad sign...

Comment: @CodyGray For those who are *wondering* , here's a short story:  Actually I was just wandering around on SO earlier today, when I saw a question that I could answer. But the code that OP posted was too long with looooong lines. And I was on tablet and on a bus. Tried to copy code to paste it into a text editor, with touch controls and movement of the bus. Took me 7-8 tries just to copy that code so that I could view all of OP's code at once. Felt a little weird that this feature is still not on SO, hence posted it as a feature request here.

Comment: https://www.gitbook.com/book/tra38/essential-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow/details

Comment: Then perhaps the real feature request should be better code formatting in the editor here. I could definitely get behind that as someone who edits a lot of poorly formatted code. I would hate to have a feature that *even more obviously* encourages copy and pasting code out of answers.